# @Async is killing Hibernate transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, asynchronous, spring-transactions

I am using an Open-Session-In-View transaction model for my REST api like this:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

This work just fine. I wanted to add @Async abilities. So I created:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(18);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(18);
        executor.initialize();
        executor.setDaemon(true);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class AsyncMarketCaller {

    @Inject
    MarketManagerFactory marketManagerFactory;

    @Async
    public Future<List<Product>> getProducts(){

        MarketManager productManager = marketManagerFactory.obtainMarketManager(market);
        result = productManager.getProducts();
        ....
    }
}
```

The productManager makes a call to another @Service

```
@Service
public class DefaultIdentifierManager implements IdentifierManager{
     @Inject
    UpcEanDAO upcEanDAO;

      @Override
    public String getTitleForIdentifier(String identifier){
        UpcEan upcEan = upcEanDAO.find(identifier);
    }
}
```

however, for  `upcEanDAO.find(identifier)` I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
```

Before I added the `@Async` ability to make async calls to `getProducts()` it worked just fine so I assume that `@Async` kills the transaction that I opened with Hibernate.

I tried adding based on another answer here, `@Transactional` to the method annotated with `@Async` but it doesn't help.

Any idea?

**EDITED**

I edited the code so

```
@Component
public class AsyncMarketCaller {

    @Inject
    AsyncMarketService asyncMarketService;

    @Async
    public Future<List<Product>> getProducts(){
        asyncMarketService.getProducts();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class AsyncMarketService {

    @Inject
    MarketManagerFactory marketManagerFactory;

    @Transactional
    public Future<List<Product>> getProducts()
     ....
}

}
```

I see in the log

```
50689 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'AsyncMarketService.getProducts' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
```

but it doesn't help. Please note that my method AsyncMarketService.getProducts doesn't call directly the DB, it calls to other methods and only one of them will make the call.

I also added above the one that actually make the call to DB:@Transactional

`49992 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'DefaultIdentifierManager.getTitleForIdentifier' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '`'

Comment: Since your transaction is commited via filter, there may not be a transaction in place when you need it.

Comment: @Hannes -  it worked before I added the Async - which is part of the filter call

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hibernate transactions work on a `ThreadLocal` basis.

As you use another thread with `@Async` there will be no transaction active.

You can achieve this functionality by having the async method calling another bean which is annotated by `@Transactional`.

Here I explain this approach a little bit more:
[How do I properly do a background thread when using Spring Data and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916104/how-do-i-properly-do-a-background-thread-when-using-spring-data-and-hibernate/24917195#24917195)

Comment: I tried your solution as you can see in the edited answer. but no help. what do you suggest?

Comment: the calls are done like this: AsyncServices->HelpService->MarketService->IdentifierService->DAOLayer to retrieve the item. I have @transactional only above HelpService method

Comment: can you try it with `void` return values? I'm not sure if that works with Futures

Comment: didn't help. I even moved the call to the class that calls the DAO directly to the AsyncService (helper) and I get the same error. how can I know if the transaction was actually opened?

Comment: now at least I see that the transaction is being opened.