# Spring Data Jpa doesn't save entity in new Thread

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a little problem when I want to save entity in other Thread. e.g.

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> userService.save(user))
```

and in userService I have a lot of logic and at the end I want to save user into database using `userRepository.save(user)` and repo doesn't save it. What am I doing wrong? If someone want more info let me know

Comment: This is probably because transactions are bound to threads by default so your new Thread doesn't have a transaction. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24917195/66686

Comment: @JensSchauder I added Transactional annotation to my service class but it's still doesn't work